# How to calculate the probability that a mutation occurred?

Tags: genetics, mutations

According to the internet, there is a 7% chance that two brown-eyed parents will have a green-eyed child. However, Dominance says that it is impossible for this to happen. Is the internet correct? If so, how is that 7% chance calculated?
source: https://www.mamanatural.com/eye-color-chart/

Comment: The "internet" is not a source. According to *who* on the internet?

Comment: "The internet" and "Dominance" are pretty vague sources. It'll help to specify the species and gene(s) involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly the site you referenced is not scientific. There is no scientific basis for a claim that "there is a 7% chance that two brown-eyed parents will have a green-eyed child".  It is correct that multiple genes determine eye color, and the effects of some depend on the versions (alleles) of the other genes present, so predicting eye color is not as straightforward as it might seem.

Comment: Not to mention that it will depend on the specific family tree you are looking at and how many ancestors with different eye colors you can find in that tree. I'm sure there will  be combinations that result in a 7% chance. But there will also be various others.

Comment: https://www.mamanatural.com/eye-color-chart/ this is the source